# NestJS/TypeORM : custom repository + multiple databases

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I make code by nestjs docs ([custom repository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository), [multiple databases](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases-1))

And here is my code.

```js
// app.module.ts
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            name: 'MYSQL_CONNECTION',
            type: 'mysql',
            port: 3306,
            entities: [AwsTest],
            logger: new MysqlLogger(),
            synchronize: false,
            extra: {
                connectionLimit: 10,
            },
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            name: 'ORACLE_CONNECTION',
            type: 'oracle',
            entities: [],
            synchronize: false,
            logger: new OracleLogger(),
            extra: {
                connectionLimit: 10,
            },
        }),
        TestModule,
    ],
    providers: [Logger],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

```js
// test.module.ts
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TestRepository], 'MYSQL_CONNECTION')],
    providers: [TestService],
    controllers: [TestController],
})
export class TestModule {}
```

```js
// test.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor(private readonly testRepository: TestRepository) {}
    async getAwsTest() {
        return await this.testRepository.getAwsTest()
    }
}
```

```js
// test.repository.ts
@EntityRepository(AwsTest)
export class TestRepository extends BaseRepository<AwsTest> {
    async getAwsTest() {
        return await this.find()
    }
}
```

```js
// aws-test.entity.ts
@Entity('test', { database: 'report' })
export class AwsTest {
    constructor(name: string, address: string) {
        this._name = name
        this._address = address
    }

    @Column('varchar', { primary: true, name: 'name' })
    readonly _name: string

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'address' })
    readonly _address: string
}
```

In this situation, nest application is not running.
Here is error console.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TestService (?). Please make sure that the argument TestRepository at index [0] is available in the TestModule context.

Potential solutions:

If TestRepository is a provider, is it part of the current TestModule?
If TestRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TestModule? @Module({ imports: [ /* the Module containing TestRepository */ ] })
```

I need your help..... (In app.module.ts, i make invisible critical information like host, username, password, database, sid...)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try injecting your repository like this:

```
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(AwsTest, 'MYSQL_CONNECTION') private readonly testRepository: TestRepository,
) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into app.module.ts file

```
@Module({
  // Database connection
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TestRepository], 'MYSQL_CONNECTION')
})
```